# Gmail unusual activity but no alert

Tags: security, gmail

From time to time, I check the Gmail "Last account activity" log. I live in Belgium and mainly use the usual Gmail website. Yesterday, I noticed there was two mobile connections from France, with this IP address: 193.253.141.64

This morning, I saw a third connection with this very IP.

How comes I didn't receive any alert from Gmail for this unusual activity?

Is there something I should do beside modifying my password and scanning my computer?

Comment: Consider using two-factor authentication (https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that Gmail didn't consider the access suspicious, since Belgium and France are close (I'm not sure what parameters Gmail uses to consider an access unusual). [This article here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) may help you, specially this portion:

> In addition, if you access Gmail on a mobile device, your login history will contain mobile logins that may appear to come from your carrier’s mobile Internet gateway(s). **Note that mobile gateways may be in a geographic location far from the area where you’re accessing your account.** If the address belongs to your mobile provider, this is considered legitimate access to your account.

If you don't access your gmail though your mobile phone, you can try the following:

- Check your **Alert preference** on the bottom portion of the Activity information window on Gmail and see if a possible attacker didn't turn it off
- Check your whole activity for your Google account through [this link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity)
- As other users have pointed out, you may enable two-factor authentication (that's probably the most important thing) and change your password.

Comment: Indeed. As I changed the password, my smartphone's gmail app required this new password too. As soon as it did reconnect to gmail, a new connection with this french ip appeared in the log.

"If the address belongs to your mobile provider,"

Well my provider is a belgian provider, not Orange, but...

Answer (score 1):

Belgium and France - that is not an unlikely scenario. That IP is from the south of France, Orange. Make sure you're not a victim of DHCP hijacking, and a MITM attack. It's an unlikely scenario, but not impossible. You can set the DHCP setting of your computer to 8.8.8.8 (Google) or OpenDNS.

Change your password. Use two factor. If you find this a hassle, always having to use Authenticator to login to your Gmail, you can create application specific logins, so using email clients is no problem.